# Unable to download non text files via web interface

Tags: gitlab

I have a self hosted GitLab server running via Apache Proxy and using the latest version on a Centos 7 machine.

All the GIT features are working correctly, the problem shows up on web interface. I suspect its something with file permission but I am unable to find any more information about it.

All of the sympthons I encountered:
 - Downloading a project archives returns and Empty archive.zip
 - Previewing a committed image returns empty image (it gives no error, has no size and shows broken icon image)

Here is a relevant entry of the production.log:

```
Started GET "/iot/visual-identity/blob/master/logo/logo(svetli).png" for *.*.*.* at 2016-06-01 08:15:51 +0200
Processing by Projects::BlobController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"iot", "project_id"=>"visual-identity", "id"=>"master/logo/logo(svetli).png"}
Read fragment views/iot/visual-identity/f8925065549a84b58177358e5ae9aaa7c0b506bf/application_settings/1-20160510215916571808000/0/e2d1b561d6b1e6374a71e983d36f0a1a (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 551ms (Views: 415.8ms | ActiveRecord: 34.3ms)
Started GET "/iot/visual-identity/raw/527cc71c13df532543758fe97c8d0a6c96bed703/logo/logo(svetli).png" for *.*.*.* at 2016-06-01 08:15:51 +0200
Processing by Projects::RawController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"iot", "project_id"=>"visual-identity", "id"=>"527cc71c13df532543758fe97c8d0a6c96bed703/logo/logo(svetli).png"}
```

I have attached the screenshot of uploaded image:

[GitLab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMJEK.png)

Apache Proxy config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName host.url
    ServerAlias www.host.url
    DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
    ServerAdmin admin@host.url

    ErrorLog /var/www/host.url/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/host.url/requests.log combined



    <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
        ServerEnvironment apache apache
    </IfModule>

    ServerSignature Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
    Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

    ProxyPass /.well-known/ !

    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
        ProxyPassReverse http://host.url/
    </Location>

    ProxyTimeout 600

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.url/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.url/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.url/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You see any error messages in the GitLab log?

Comment: Added production.log above. Also a screenshot. The thing is, there is no error either in GitLab or in browser for missing image. When inspecting element, the image has size of 0 bytes (same as downloaded .zip-ed project)

Comment: After one year, the problem still persists. Duo to some other problems I have reinstalled GitLab, updating it regularly and updated Proxy configuration. It fixed all problems except for this one. I have updated it with proxy configuration, as I have a feeling its connected with that.